# Does shielding Digital lines and IC's with metal enclosures assist in reducing noise on close by analog lines and IC's on the same PCB

Tags: precision, noise, adc

I have digital and analog IC's on the same PCB, These have separate ground pours with a common ground connection on one place of the PCB. Would it help in anyway to shield the digital components, by soldering metal shield enclosures over them, to reduce the amount of noise they create for the analog components in addition to all the normal best practices of good PCB layout.

I know soldering metal shields over very sensitive analog components can shield them from noise but what about doing the digital stuff too? specifically fast SPI lines and microcontrollers?